# Need to remove remove a pattern/string in regular expression (notepad ++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help with regular expression to remove a pattern from a text file. My string looks like:

```
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\493\044\56767957.Z.jpg
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\532\818\10313817.A.jpg
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\532\823\10313817.G.jpg
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\532\825\10313817.E.jpg
```

where, I need to remove everything starting

```
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\493\044\
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\532\818\
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\532\823\
\\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\067\532\825\
```

and I just need to have the number.character.jpg 
56767957.Z.jpg, 10313817.A.jpg, 10313817.G.jpg, 10313817.E.jpg

I have tried something like:                                     \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}---INFO---ImageUpload successful:

on string: 16.09.2019 10:06:55---WARN---ImageUpload fail: D130001001443667;9130001001443667;\immfileandback\Volumes\Volume0\opasdata\d130001\derivates\1\001\443\667\4026325897404.B.jpg;P10;06;29;2E;V1067607Y;

this removes '16.09.2019 10:06:55---WARN---ImageUpload fail:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for

```
\\\\.*\\
```

or for

```
^.*\\
```

and replace with nothing

Search mode: "Regular expression"

Make sure to un-check the box for ". matches new line"